# Locale getDisplayLanguage broken in jlink Image

Tags: java, locale, jlink

Here an SSCCE:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale item = Locale.FRANCE;
        System.out.println("Locale: "+item+" displayed: "+item.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.GERMANY));
    }
}
```

When compiling and running it, it correctly displays

```
Locale: fr_FR displayed: Französisch
```

But if I now create a custom runtime image through jlink and run it with it, I get:

```
Locale: fr_FR displayed: French
```

No matter which Locale is used, it always falls back to the English one it seems. Perhaps I need an additional module for this? The runtime image is generated like follows:

```
jlink --module-path "..." --add-modules=java.desktop,java.logging,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.media --output image
```

My JDK version:

```
$ java --version
java 11.0.2 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java11locales-5069639.html), the java.base module only includes the English locale. To build a Jlink image which includes the other locales as well, one must add the jdk.localedata module.